Some questions with 2 tags can't be found by [tag1][tag2], why?
By searching hana and isolation level, three question and answers are shown; all of them also have the tag isolation-level:

If I search with the two tags hana and isolation-level, there are no results:

What is the reason?

In the first case, you are not looking for a tag for "isolation level". And in the second case, you are looking for unanswered questions.

Note that when you search for tags only, the search redirects to /questions/tagged/<tag>+<tag2> i.e. you'll only see questions, not answers. But your first search also lists answers.

As cafce25 pointed out, it looks like this is just because you've also filtered by "Unanswered"
If you explicitly pass the tab in the url (or just navigate to it), the question with both tags should show up.


Thanks, I didn't pay attention to the "0 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers", it's probably one year that I clicked "unanswered". Maybe I'd post a feature request to have a consistent search whatever a tag or not a tag is searched... (for a better user experience)

FWIW, I've been bitten by this before too.
